# Dojo: FilteringSelect template

Tags: javascript, html, web, dojo

I'm trying to modify Dojo FilteringSelect to disable typing into it. I'm aware I can just easily do

```
postCreate: function() {
      this.inherited(arguments);
      this.textbox.readOnly = true;
}
```

However that's not what I'm aiming for. There's a template string which is being added to the component which is inherited from ValidationTextBox and I'd like to modify that one.

Could anyone kindly help me, how to modify the templateString which is being inherited from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this using the native dijit ecosystem depending on how you are instantiating the Filtering Select.

You can use either the `readOnly` or `disabled` properties to achieve the affect you want, with each having slightly different uses.

declaratively:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/FilteringSelect" data-dojo-props="disabled:true"></div>
```

Programmatically:

```
new FilteringSelect({
  disabled:true
});
```

Based on what is stated, I don't think modifying the templateString is necessary, as it could break other functionality of the FilteringSelect, at which point you might as well use a different component altogether.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. What I'm actually aiming for is modifying `<input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" type="text" autocomplete="off" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" role="textbox" aria-required="true" tabindex="0" id="fs" value="" readonly="">` To explain why I'm trying to achieve it this way is that I'm looking into potentially modifying filteringSelect to use <select><option></option></select> tags rather than <input>s.

Comment: Ah okay that makes more sense.  You'll want to look at DropDownBox.html in the `dijit/form/templates` source since I believe that is the template used for the Filtering Select.  The other thing to note is the html attributes are simply `readonly` and `disabled`, not `readonly=""`. Most browsers recognize both forms, but not all.

Comment: Yeah I do understand that. I'm having really a hard time getting into my head how to do this. I'm inheriting FilteringSelect as follows `var _filteringSelect = declare([FilteringSelect], {
templateString = "myTemplateString" })` That's all good apart from some of the templatecode being inherited from somewhere else and I'm unable to figure out how to modify these templatestrings. Thanks.

Comment: Ah nevermind, I understand now. Thanks again for your help. Solution to this is just indeed modifying the DropDownBox.html template.